# Why does OpenAPI generate Java members/methods with underscore prefixes?

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have an OpenAPI model I'm rendering in Java. In the context (of OpenFGA) there's a model for an "object", as in, the object of a relationship. In any case it's called "object" in the model

When I render the model, I end up with member variables and methods called `_object` instead.

Member variables end up looking like:

```
    public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_OBJECT = "object";
    private String _object;
```

...and methods like:

```
    public TupleKey _object(String _object) {
        this._object = _object;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Get _object
     * @return _object
     **/
    @javax.annotation.Nullable
    @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_OBJECT)
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    public String getObject() {
        return _object;
    }

    @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_OBJECT)
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    public void setObject(String _object) {
        this._object = _object;
    }

    public TupleKey relation(String relation) {
        this.relation = relation;
        return this;
    }
```

Why `_object`? If `object` is not a keyword in Java, we don't need a leading underscore, right? I see the same happen with `_list` and `_file` as well.

Comment: You will have to ask whoever added `object`, `file` and `list` to the [reserved words list for the Java generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/#reserved-words)

Comment: Could be so every name can be legal, including names starting with numbers. `9foo` (illegal java identifier) becomes `_9foo` (legal java identifier).

Comment: Object, List, and File are already defined in Java Platform.

Comment: @pcalkins But are different than object, list, and file. By that argument any existing JDK class could exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "reserved word" for OpenAPI generator's Java processor. ([docs](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/#reserved-words), [code](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/2cfce7cd2d54f42f0d64bc96c87829a2f99f58ce/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java#L184)) Reserved words for Java that get processed by OpenAPI generator end up prefixing an underscore.

As far as I can tell, the only way to opt out of this is to either patch OpenAPI or do post-processing. (Maybe someone in comments can correct me, though)

---

While `object` is not a reserved keyword in Java as a language, it might be worth leaving as `_object` since it's a reserved keyword in other JVM languages.

- In Kotlin, `object` is a keyword for an anonymous Object: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html
- In Scala, `object` is a keyword for Singleton instances: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-objects.html

Those languages support bare words to get around the keyword limitation, so `myModelThing.`object`(etc)` could be valid, but it's a pain.

While this might not be the reason it was added to OpenAPI generator's reserved words, it does mean that a client generated in Java (or derivative software) is more likely to be able to interact with other JVM languages, so unless you plan to also generate a Kotlin client and Scala client (and others?) it might be worth leaving it as-is.